# Text before price on WooCom

Tags: php, function

I want to add text before the price on the WooCommerce product catalogue only, which I have working using this code in functions.php:

```
    // Add text before price
    function bd_rrp_price_html( $price, $product ) {
        $return_string = 'Rent from: ' . $price;
        return $return_string;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'bd_rrp_price_html', 100, 2 );`
```

However, the above function is also adding the text before the price on the product detail page, which I do not want...

What would I need to change in the function to get it so it only displays on the product catalogue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**You have just to inverted the price and the text:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
function cw_change_product_price_display( $price ) {
    // Your additional text in a translatable string
    $text = __('TEXT');

    // returning the text before the price
    return $text . ' ' . $price;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This did not work. Text still shows on the product page, as well as the catalogue.